# MacOS swift3 stitch two images together

Tags: swift3, macos-sierra, nsimage, cifilter

I like to stitch two NSImages together using swift 3 in xcode.
I was able to use the "CIAdditionCompositing")method which results in a picture set inside eachother.

Now I am trying to join the two pictures along the vertical axis side by side.

Multiple examples exist for iphone IOS using UIImage which are not applicable anymore. Does anybody have an example for MacOS for NSimage?

This is the code for my CIAdditionCompositing:

```
    //------- combining images ----
    // get images from internet
    // webaddress
    let filePath2 = "https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/open_graph_logo.png?201701131218"
    let filePath1 = "https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/110/images/74627-0-1459502036.jpg"
    //create url paths
    let url1 = NSURL(string: filePath1)
    let url2 = NSURL(string: filePath2)
    //retrieve images
    let image1 = NSImage(byReferencing: url1! as URL)
    let image2 = NSImage(byReferencing: url2! as URL)
    // convert images
    //read image 1
    let imageData1 = image1.tiffRepresentation!
    let ciImgage1 = CIImage(data: imageData1)
    //read image 2
    let imageData2 = image2.tiffRepresentation!
    let ciImgage2 = CIImage(data: imageData2)

    // filtersetting
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing")!
    filter.setDefaults()
    filter.setValue(ciImgage2, forKey: "inputImage")
    filter.setValue(ciImgage1, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")
    // collect result
    let resultCIImage = filter.outputImage
    // transfer back to nsimage
    let rep = NSCIImageRep(ciImage: resultCIImage!)
    let finalResult = NSImage(size: rep.size)
    finalResult.addRepresentation(rep)

    // display result image....
    MyImage.image = finalResult
```

Comment: I don't have time to right up a good explanation or anything, but here is some code I wrote a while ago that can help you out: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/5dbb15f5331ac183e19d34d15fb835ff

Comment: Hello Alexander, I appreciate your code which takes all the frames from a GIF image, stores them into an NS and CGI array and later converts the frames into a single NSImage. I got your code to work. However, I am finding it difficult to rewrite your code to just join two JPG images and appreciate any help you can offer. Thx. Frans.

Comment: rather than obtaining those arrays from the frames of a gif, create them yourself with whatever jpg images you'd like